# Orthogonal Random Variable $\mathcal{L}^{2}$ (Hard?)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, self-learning, independence

I am self-studying Probability Theory and for me the following problem is challenging.

[image]

Comment: The characteristic function of $S_n$ is the product of the characteristic functions of the $X_j, j=1 \cdots n$ (see here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subindependence). This does not answer your question but allows you to find the distribution of $S_n$, and thus the limiting distribution if it exists.

Comment: It's easy to prove that $S_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$, and since $L^2$ is complete, you can infer that $S_n$ converges in $L^2$ to some $S$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Comment: How can we prove that $S_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ , should we use the assumption that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{E(X_n^2)} < \infty $ ?  and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{Var(X_n)} < \infty $ ? Also  how do we infer that if $L^2 $is complete then $S_n $Converges in $L^2$ to some $S$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that $S=\sum_{j=1}^\infty X_j$. To prove that the series converges, you need to show that the tails go to zero in the $L^2$-norm. So
$$
E[(\sum_{j=m}^r X_j)^2]=E[\sum_{j,k=m}^r X_jX_k]=\sum_{k,j=m}^rE(X_jX_k)=\sum_{j=m}^rE(X_j^2).
$$
The hypothesis gives you that the latter sums can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the last part ? where did we use that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{E(X_n^2)}$ and how do we conclude $S_n$ converges in $L^2$ to some $S$

Comment: A series is the limit of the sequence of partial sums. So you need to prove that the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy. That is, you need to prove that the norm of  $S_r-S_m $ can be made arbitrarily small for big enough  $m $. The estimate in the answer shows that the tails are bounded by the tails of the numeric series that you know converges.